# Name of effect move screen with mouse

Tags: html, css, effect

What is the name or how to write that effect.
[image: effect]

We click with our cursor on the bottom of the screen, then without releasing we move up our cursor and then the screen will be changed to another (next) screen.

Comment: carousal with swipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is called Carousal with swipe and maybe you are looking for a vertical carousal.

You can see the examples here:

https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/animated-vertical-bootstrap-carousel-on-mouse-scroll-and-swipe

https://github.com/avinoamr/bootstrap-carousel-swipe